# Windows 7 can't connect to wireless LAN when using WPA authentication

Tags: windows-7, wpa

I have a Dell latitude d830 running Windows 7 and a Belking 54G WiFi router which is using WPA authentication (TKIP). The problem is that Windows can detect the WLAN and gives me option to connect and even asks for the WPA key but when I enter the key and try to connect, I get message "Windows was unable to connect". I have tried connecting with other devices (a symbian mobile, iPhone, and the same machine running Windows XP pro, they all connect without any problem). Also if I turn off the WPA authentication or use WEP, it connects fine with Windows 7 but I do not want to turn it off or use WEP due to obvious reasons.

I have seen many people facing same problem with Windows 7 posting on the Internet which suggests that this is a Windows 7 issue than anything else.

Is there any solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

The wireless adapter card is **"Intel PRO Wireless 3945ABG"**

Comment: Does it work with WPA-PSK or AES? Or could you set the router to WPA2?

Comment: No it does not work with WPA-PSK either and no the router only supports WPA authentication, even with latest firmware upgrade.

Comment: You should have a look for same...

[http://superuser.com/questions/455815/windows-7-computer-cant-connect-to-wifi-using-any-adapter/455870#455870][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/455815/windows-7-computer-cant-connect-to-wifi-using-any-adapter/455870#455870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to hear that you keep having trouble, despite repeated efforts to solve it. This isn't likely a Windows-7 issue as you describe, it is more likely an issue with the driver for that particular wireless network card.

Unfortunately [Dell support](http://support.dell.com/) doesn't offer any Windows 7 specific updates for that model, but if you can update your question with the specific wireless card that is in your laptop (preferably with the PCI Vendor and Device ID - they are four hex characters each - see image below, in this case they are 8086 and 10BD). Hopefully we can help get you a driver that works properly under Windows 7 for all wireless network types.

Here is the link for Intel downloads for the 3945ABG card: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless+Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+WiFi+Products&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+PRO%2fWireless+3945ABG+Network+Connection&ProdId=2259&LineId=1784&FamilyId=1783

Pick the correct 32/64 bit driver for your laptop and see if that makes any difference.

If that doesn't pan out for some reason, the D830 uses a pretty standard mini-pci card for wireless duties. A search on [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&Description=mini-pci) yields a few options around $20-$30 USD. Certainly eBay would have some great older model cards that have better Windows 7 support.

You could also try to contact [Intel Support](http://www.intel.com/support/feedback.htm?group=network) and describe your issue. The have a page stating that the 2200BG card is not supported under Windows 7, and the 3945 series didn't come too long after. It could be something in their Win7 driver that WPA support is broken.

[image: Device Manager - Network Device Properties - Details Tab]

Comment: I have updated the question and put in the adapter model number. Will get the device and vendor IDs later in the evening (am at work right now).

Comment: Well I have tried the drivers from Intel and that didn't solve the problem. Seems like I'd have to get a mini-pci card after all. Thanks for your help though...

Answer (score 0):

See if your router has MAC address filtering enabled. If it does, enter your wireless card's MAC address in the router or simply disable the filtering.

Comment: the same machine is able to connect with Windows XP Pro though